# Filling and submitting forms with mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to fill a form and submit it using `mechanize`. I manage some inputs all rights, but there is one field that is giving me trouble, and I don't know exactly why. The input tag looks like this:

```
<input type="text" title="bla" id="captch" name="captcha">
```

I then do

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.select_form(name="myForm")    

br.form["captcha"] = '123456'

res = br.submit()
print res.read()
```

The response I print tells me that I left that input blank.

I suspect part of the reason is, there's no attribute `value` to this input field. This is what I suspect because my other inputs look like

```
<input tabindex="1" name="whatever" value="">
```

, and they get filled all right. But it's only a suspicion.

Questions: (i) is my suspicion right? (ii) in either case, how to solve this?

Comment: could you post the output of `print res.read()` here

Comment: it's basically the same page, reloaded. this happens when, and only when, the input "captcha" is left blank.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
form.field_with(:id => 'captcha').value = '123456'
```